# Comparison of file list with files in folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of filenames but in the directory they are named a little different. I wanna print filenames that are not in directory. Example of files:

`FOO_BAR_524B_023D9B01_2021-157T05-34-31__00001_2021-08-30T124702.130.tgz`

```
import os
missing = ['FOO_BAR_524B_023D9B01_2021-157T05-34-31__00001', 'dfiknvbdjfhnv']
for fileName in missing:
    for fileNames in next(os.walk('C:\\Users\\foo\\bar'))[2]:
        if fileName not in fileNames:
            print(fileName)
```

I cannot get what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Why do you think that you are doing something wrong?

Comment: @mkrieger1 because in out i get:
`FOO_BAR_524B_023D9B01_2021-157T05-34-31__00001
FOO_BAR_524B_023D9B01_2021-157T05-34-31__00001
FOO_BAR_524B_023D9B01_2021-157T05-34-31__00001
FOO_BAR_524B_023D9B01_2021-157T05-34-31__00001
dfiknvbdjfhnv
dfiknvbdjfhnv
dfiknvbdjfhnv
dfiknvbdjfhnv
dfiknvbdjfhnv`

Comment: I thought i should get only value `'dfiknvbdjfhnv'` in case if `FOO_BAR_524B_023D9B01_2021-157T05-34-31__00001_2021-08-30T124702.130.tgz` file is in folder

Comment: Please update the question with an example of input and expected output versus real output. That way we can help in a more efficient manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you iterate over every file in the directory (`for fileNames in next(os.walk(...))[2]`) and check if `fileName` is in each of those file names. For every file in the folder where `fileName not in fileNames`, `fileName` is printed, resulting in it being printed many times.

This can be fixed by doing a single check to see if all files in the folder do not contain the target file name.

```
import os
missing = ['FOO_BAR_524B_023D9B01_2021-157T05-34-31__00001', 'dfiknvbdjfhnv']
fileNames = next(os.walk('C:\\Users\\foo\\bar'))[2]
for missingfileName in missing:
    if all(missingfileName not in fileName for fileName in fileNames):
        print(missingfileName)
```

If you want it to be more efficient and you are only looking for file names that are prefixes of other names, then you can use a data structure called a trie. For example if `missing` equals `['bcd']`, and there is a file called `abcde` and these are **not** considered a match, then a trie is appropriate here.

Comment: thanks a lot man that works great for me!!!
but in out u should print `missingfileName` otherwise its printing err